# Navigation bar background image won't fit

Tags: swift, uiimage, uinavigationbar, background-image

I was told a `UIImage` should be 320x44 and 640x88 if you want it to fit on a `UINavigationBar` as a background image. When I use `setBackgroundImage` to set the image programmatically, the background image shows up multiple times on the navigation bar to fill up the bar. Am I supposed to add more code to configure the background image correctly? I tried setting the `contentMode` to `.scaleAspectFit` but it didn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Those dimensions would be valid for the iPhone 5 series and earlier.

Comment: @rmaddy so what dimensions am I supposed to use for everything post-iPhone 5?

Comment: Whatever the width of the given device is. And if you need to support landscape, it would be a whole other set of dimensions. This all assumes of course that you need an image that is the full size of the nav bar.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, but just to be clear: it's not possible to fill up the navigation bar by stretching the image, is it? I would like to stretch it the same way you stretch it to fill up a `UIImageView`.

Comment: @rmaddy it didn't work. I resized my image to the dimensions of my device but it's still showing the background image multiple times to fill.

Comment: Try setting the content mode of the imageView to scaleAspectFill maybe?

Comment: @iDeveloper A navigation bar doesn't have an image view. It only has a background image property, which returns a `UIImage`.

Comment: Oh my bad. Didn't look into it much I guess.